# Add Google Account to Elementary Loki

Tags: settings, release-loki

On my Elementary Loki installation there is no option to add a google account in the switchboard-onlineaccounts plug. If i remember correctly, this was possible in Freya. Is this feature removed? or am i missing packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switchboard-onlineaccounts didn't make it into the stable version of Freya. An incomplete version of this plug was in the Freya beta but was [removed](https://answers.launchpad.net/switchboard/+question/265013) before the stable release.

Loki beta 2 (the latest version as of this writing) has known bugs and may be missing features. It's possible that the [new version of the plug](https://launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-onlineaccounts/+announcement/14102), which was released after Beta 2 and will probably ship with RC1, may fix this problem.